# Convert English day name to Japanese in blade php

Tags: php, laravel-blade, cjk

How can I convert English day name to Japanese in blade php? For now I have this code in converting date to Japanese in my blade template:

```
<h5 class="event-date">{{ date("Y", strtotime($event->event_date)) . '年' . date("m", strtotime($event->event_date)) . '月' . date("d", strtotime($event->event_date)) . '日' . ' (' . date("D", strtotime($event->event_date)) . ')' }}</h5>
```

This outputs:

```
 2019年03月21日 (Thu)
```

This is their conversion from Sun-Sat respectively:

```
"日","月","火","水","木","金","土"
```

But how can I make it to Japanese? Also, do you have any suggestions to make my formatting shorter in blade file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create translate file in `resources/lang/jp/days.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    'Thu' => '木曜日'
];
```

In your blade file use this:

```
{{ trans('days.' . date("D", strtotime($event->event_date)), [], 'jp') }}
```

Comment: Error : `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Translation\Translator::trans() must be of the type array, null given,`

Comment: It works now. But do you have any suggestions on how to shorten my date formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setlocale** function to make it Japanese like that:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja.UTF-8');
```

Comment: Where can I insert that in blade file?

Comment: Just add top of your codes and use **strtotime** function alone, its will change the language automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old thread but to others who stumbled upon this post while searching for an answer, recent Carbon versions (most probably, Carbon from Laravel 5.5+) allows the usage of `Carbon::locale('')->translatedFormat('')` wherein the `locale` specifies what language will be used while `translatedFormat` works similar to `format` function.

Example:

```php
$announcement->created_at->locale('ja_JP')->translatedFormat('M d, Y');
// Output: 10月 23, 2022
```

Here's the official example of Carbon:
[Try Carbon](https://try-carbon-package.herokuapp.com/?hide-output-gutter&output-left-padding=10&theme=tomorrow_night&border=none&radius=4&v-padding=15&input=%24date%20%3D%20Carbon%3A%3Aparse(%272018-03-16%2015%3A45%27)-%3Elocale(%27uk%27)%3B%0A%0Aecho%20%24date-%3EtranslatedFormat(%27g%3Ai%20a%20l%20jS%20F%20Y%27)%3B%20%2F%2F%203%3A45%20%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%E2%80%99%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F%2016-%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%202018%0A&token=live-editor-138)

This can be found in their documentation as well, below the table:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#supported-locales